# Why can't i use the void main?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
#define COUNT 10
void main()
{
 void print_NUM(void);
 int add_values(void);
 void print_out(int);
 int SUM;

 print_NUM();
 SUM=add_values();
 print_out(SUM);
}

void print_NUM()
{
 cout << "This program adds " << COUNT << " integers\n";
 cout << "Please enter " << COUNT << " integers to be added\n";
}
```

I can't run it because it said that the main should be int but this is a direct copy from my lecture notes and the only way to get the answer that I need is when I use int main instead. Why is that?

Comment: Because lecture notes tend to be full of errors?

Comment: Your lecture notes are ancient and have been incorrect for decades, but whoever wrote them can't be bothered to do anything about it.

Answer (score 3):

C++ standard says that main function has to be of form
`int main()` or `int main(int, char**)` (of course auto with trailing return types works as well). Any other form is implementation defined http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.main#2. Lectures tend to be full of errors and schools teach bad practices/not standard compliant code all the time.

Comment: Thank you this helps me a lot :D

Comment: Please mark Answer as right, so that it can help others too. :)

Answer (score 0):

The C langs (C and C++) return an integer from the main function. This is mainly for exit codes. Try changing "void" to "int".

Answer (score 0):

> Why can't i use the void main?

Because the rules of the language say that `main` must return `int`. Violating that rule makes your program ill-formed, which means that compilers are required to issue a diagnostic message, and are allowed to refuse to compile the program. Hence, the error.

> but this is a direct copy from my lecture notes

Your lecturer didn't teach you standard C++.

This used to be allowed in some old C++ dialects that pre date the standardisation. That was a long time ago.